# loadUrl finaliza (crash) o aplicativo no Android

Tags: android, android-webview

Ao usar `WebView.loadUrl(url);` no Android o em algumas versões do Android o aplicativo finaliza sozinho ("crash"), no caso a falha ocorreu na versões 6 e 7 do Android.

**Notas:**

- O *Host GPU* está ativado nos emuladores
- O problema ocorre em celulares também

A única maneira do problema não ocorre foi [desativar a aceleração de hardware assim](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/164166/3635):

```
<activity android:hardwareAccelerated="false" />
```

Mas isto torna a performance do aplicativo pior, gostaria de usar a aceleração e "evitar" que o erro ocorra.

Eu adicionei as permissões (isto porque o minSdk é o 19):

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="com.example.guilherme.webviewexample">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

O `build.gradle` está assim:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.0"

...
```

E o código assim:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    myWebView  = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.myWebView);

    WebViewClient clientInterface = new WebViewClient();

    WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.myWebView);

    WebSettings wbset = myWebView.getSettings();
    wbset.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    myWebView.setWebViewClient(clientInterface);

    String url = "http://pt.stackoverflow.com";

    myWebView.loadUrl(url);
}
```

Eu acredito que o erro seja este:

> GLES2DecoderImpl::ResizeOffscreenFrameBuffer failed to allocate storage for offscreen target depth buffer.

Segue o LOG no momento do crash:

> ```
> 11-10 10:52:13.779 22603-22603/com.example.guilherme.webviewexample I/chromium: [INFO:async_pixel_transfer_manager_android.cc(56)] Async pixel transfers not supported
> 11-10 10:52:13.809 22603-22603/com.example.guilherme.webviewexample E/chromium: [ERROR:gles2_cmd_decoder.cc(3389)] GLES2DecoderImpl::ResizeOffscreenFrameBuffer failed to allocate storage for offscreen target depth buffer.
> 11-10 10:52:13.809 22603-22603/com.example.guilherme.webviewexample E/chromium: [ERROR:gles2_cmd_decoder.cc(2433)] Could not allocate offscreen buffer storage.
> 11-10 10:52:13.809 22603-22603/com.example.guilherme.webviewexample E/chromium: [ERROR:in_process_command_buffer.cc(465)] Could not initialize decoder.
> 11-10 10:52:13.809 22603-22603/com.example.guilherme.webviewexample A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000048 (code=1), thread 22603 (.webviewexample)
> ```

Comment: Caraca, eu executei exatamente o mesmo código aqui e rolou de boas, um Clean Project será que não ajuda?

Comment: @LeonardoDias eu criei um projeto do zero e mesmo assim não deu certo :/ ... talvez seja algo com meu IDE ou compilador, não sei se faz diferença, mas antes eu usava windows8 agora estou usando Windows7

Comment: Bom...pelo que li, o webview dos aparelhos deve estar desatualizado (posso estar errado).
Quando as permissões em tempo real, dá uma lida aqui...https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html
É tranquilo mexer nisso.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento [Verifique se o emulador/dispositivo tem memória suficiente](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21652076/webview-loadurl-shows-white-screen)

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento veja se essa questão [ajuda](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20554621/after-a-while-of-usage-my-app-freezes-during-scrolling-a-webview-saying-could), aparentemente a Webview não é corretamente destruída no final da aplicação.