# Como detectar se o sistema suporta aceleração de hardware?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-manifest

Atualmente faço isto para que uma das minhas `activity` que requerem aceleração funcionem:

```
<application android:hardwareAccelerated="true">
    <activity ... />
    <activity android:hardwareAccelerated="false" />
</application>
```

Caso contrário o aplicativo trava e fecha (crash) e no log obtenho o seguinte erro:

> 04-23 05:27:36.570: E/chromium(902): [ERROR:gles2_cmd_decoder.cc(3389)] GLES2DecoderImpl::ResizeOffscreenFrameBuffer failed to allocate storage for offscreen target depth buffer.

Todavia gostaria de detectar se existe suporte para aceleração de hardware e ativa-lo, isto pode ser pelo manifest quanto por java. É possível?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A aceleração por hardware está disponível com o Android 3.0 (API level 11).
A partir do Android 4.0(API level 14) ela é habilitada por padrão.

A aceleração por hardware pode ser controlada aos seguintes níveis:

- **Application**
  No *AndroidManifest.xml*, indicando `true` ou `false` ao atributo `android:hardwareAccelerated`, na secção `<application/>`:

  ```
  <application android:hardwareAccelerated="true" ...>
  ```
- **Activity**
  No *AndroidManifest.xml*, indicando `true` ou `false` ao atributo `android:hardwareAccelerated`, na secção `<activity/>`:

  ```
  <application android:hardwareAccelerated="true">
      <activity ... />
      <activity android:hardwareAccelerated="false" />
  </application>
  ```
- **Window**
  Usando o método `setFlags()` da Window para habilitar a aceleração por hardware:

  ```
  getWindow().setFlags(
      WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_HARDWARE_ACCELERATED,
      WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_HARDWARE_ACCELERATED);
  ```

  Neste nível não é possível desabilitar aceleração por hardware.
- **View**
  Usando o método `setLayerType()` da *View* para desabilitar a aceleração por hardware:

  ```
  myView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
  ```

  Neste nível não é possível habilitar aceleração por hardware.

Existem duas formas de saber se uma aplicação é acelerada por hardware:

- [View.isHardwareAccelerated()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#isHardwareAccelerated())
  Retorna `true` se a *View* está associada a uma *Window* acelerada por hardware.
- [Canvas.isHardwareAccelerated()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#isHardwareAccelerated())
  Retorna `true` se o *Canvas* é acelerado por hardware.

Note que antes de utilizar o método tem de ter a garantia de que a *View* está associada a uma *Window*, o que não é o caso por exemplo no onCreate().

Um local onde tem essa garantia é o [onWindowFocusChanged()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onWindowFocusChanged(boolean)) da Activity.

```
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
    if(hasFocus){
        boolean isAccelerated = view.isHardwareAccelerated();
    }

}
```

Para informação mais detalhada ver o tópico [Hardware Acceleration](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/hardware-accel.html) na documentação.

Comment: Não, `getWindow()` é um método da Activity, ele retorna a *Window* dessa *Activity*.

Comment: Você fala "Ambos ...." mas depois não concretiza, suponho que queria dizer "ambos ......, mesmo eu tendo ...., **retornam false**". Não sei se esses métodos são correctamente emulados. Talvez tenha de testar em dispositivos físicos. Note que é algo que eu nunca usei, a resposta foi baseada na documentação.

Comment: Tem de ter atenção que antes de utilizar o método a view tem de estar associada a uma Window. Veja a edição da resposta.

Comment: O testei o exemplo que postei, utilizando o `onWindowFocusChanged()`, e ele funcionou.

Comment: Não sei onde ou como você pretende usar os métodos mas sei que o `Canvas.isHardwareAccelerated()` dentro do método `draw()`de uma *View* também funciona.

Comment: Ramaral estou começando a acreditar que o problema não seja aceleração, eu obtenho este erro `GLES2DecoderImpl::ResizeOffscreenFrameBuffer failed to allocate storage for offscreen target depth buffer`, isto quando a aceleração esta configurada no manifest assim `<activity android:hardwareAccelerated="false" />` e no caso somente ocorre se eu usar um `webView.loadUrl`. Vou marcar esta resposta como correta, pois parece que ambos problemas não estão relacionados. Por favor veja esta outra pergunta http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/163926/3635

Comment: Só uma correção eu escrevi isto `<activity android:hardwareAccelerated="false" />`, mas na verdade eu queria dizer isto `<activity android:hardwareAccelerated="true" />`, não teria sentido o `false` na maioria dos testes que fiz. Obrigado mais uma vez. Uma nota, a pergunta sobre webView eu alterei.